# HowTo init Django model, before using it?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django.

*Apps | Versions*:

- Python 2.6.2
- Django (working with PostgreSQL)

**Question**: I wrote a simple model:

```
class OperationType(models.Model):
    eid            = models.IntegerField()
    name           = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description    = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        tpl = 'eid="', str(self.eid), '" name="', self.name, '"'
        return ''.join(tpl)
```

Now I need to initialize it, for example with this data:

```
0, "None"
1, "Add"
2, "Edit"
3, "Delete"
```

But I need to initialize this data not with admin web panel, but after class model created in the same code. How to do this?

Thanks for help!

---

**ADDED:**
file `initial_data.json`:

```
[
  {
    "model": "OperationType",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "eid": 0,
      "name": "None",
      "description": "Do nothing"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "OperationType",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "eid": 1,
      "name": "Add",
      "description": "Adding transaction"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your `__unicode__()` isn't returning a `unicode`. You may want to fix that before it blows up in your face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use initial_data.json file, with content (added to the question), but when I run *python manage.py syncdb*, It return me the error: *DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'OperationType'*? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Done! :) i was need *accounting.operationtype*!

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixtures, check the [Django Document](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture).